# Connecting to database on users computer

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection, netbeans-8

I am currently using Netbeans 8 and trying to make the MySQL database connect to the program without downloading MySQL on to the users computer or running a server, so the MySQL file must be local. How may I proceed is there a way to package with the jar of the program or should I proceed another way.

Also here is the code that connect to the database.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chutesandladders", name, password);
            Statement update = conn.createStatement();
```

Comment: Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: 1) MySQL does not us a "file" you can use without the MySQL server process. Use SQLite if you need a database in a file. 2) I see no Java code in your question, so I've remove the `Java` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to package a MySQL "file" in JAR. MySQL *always* runs as a server process that you can connect to using JDBC.

The JDB URL `dbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chutesandladders` from your question contains the hostname `localhost` and the port `3306` where the MySQL server is running.

If you want a client on a different machine to connect to this server, you must use the real hostname of the server in the JDBC URL. Of course you must allow access from this client to the server.

**Edit:** If you must use a relational database but can not access a server, you should use an embedded database. A widely used is [H2](http://h2database.com/html/main.html).

Comment: How may I make a local server on the users computer when the user does not have mysql?

Comment: You can't. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm currently doing a project and the scenario is that we are distributing the code and it must be ready to play on anyone's computer.

Comment: How then may I make a local server run on the users computer?

Comment: This is not possible with MySQL. You can use H2. See my edited answer.